# Total Blackness after Bumblebee uninstall

Tags: boot, nvidia, uninstall, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm new to Linux and was until 1hr ago a huge fan! Now I think I've managed to to turn my laptop (Asus Vivobook i5, SSD) into a paperweight by uninstalling Bumblebee (incorrectly?)

I used this command to uninstall it:

sudo apt-get remove bumblebee-nvidia

After the reboot I only get a black screen. I can hear it get to the login screen but nothing happens. I can't get into the boot menu - tried F2, Del, Esc, F10 during startup and nothing happens. I've removed the harddrive and tried to boot of a USB with Ubuntu on it and all I get is a black screen. I never see the Asus Logo or any other indication on the screen - it's just black.

My feeling is that I have somehow broken the hybrid graphics card.

Does anyone know how to reset this ... or fix this somehow?

Else I have to buy a new laptop.

Comment: If you removed the hard drive and it still does not boot from the USB then I don't think this is related to bumblebee becuase it cannot brick (paperweight) a PC

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've uninstalled bumblebee without uninstalling the graphics driver. When you see the black screen, press CTRL + ALT + 1 (or F1 - try both) to bring up a console. Log in with your username and password. From here, uninstall your graphics driver (sudo apt-get remove nvidia-driver) or re-install bumblebee (sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia). Afterwards, restart.

The black screen you're experiencing is because of the normal nvidia driver. See, everything in Linux happens through something called X. When you install nvidia-driver, it edits the config file for X (or you do) in order to avoid the black screen. But with optimus laptops, you need to pay around with it quite a bit more (aided only by Nvidia's own vague instructions). The only reason it's like this is because nvidia doesn't feel like doing anything about it.

It's no wonder Linux Torvalds cursed at NVIDIA.